# Using Set-Acl and the FileSystemAccessRule.RemoveAccessRule method not working

Tags: windows, powershell, acl

### Summary:

I'm trying to script removing the modify permission of a particular folder (or file) for the "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users" group, across multiple machines (actually as part of a file deployment script). I have some code that attempts to do this, but it is not working as expected.

### Context:

The script copies down a file structure locally, and a particular file (ideally the whole folder structure) needs to be made unmodifiable (by non-admins). Setting the read-only setting isn't sufficient, since it can be reverted by those with modify permissions to the file.

### My attempt:

```
$folder = "C:\folder"
$file = "C:\folder\file.ext"

# Get the existing ACL
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $folder

# See what it looks like
$acl.Access | ft

# Target and remove the specific modify rule
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users","Modify","Allow")
$acl.RemoveAccessRule($rule)

# Check that the modification to the PS object took
$acl.Access | ft

# Perform the modification
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $folder

# Check that the modification to the folder/file took
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $folder
$acl.Access | ft
```

### My results:

The `.RemoveAccessRule()` call has no effect on the ACL (even though it returns `True`), as shown by the second `$acl.Access | ft`. As such, the `Set-Acl` call has no effect either. I suspect that perhaps I'm not targeting the rule I want correctly, and perhaps the `.RemoveAccessRule()` call is returning `True` just because there were technically no "failures". But that's just a shot in the dark.

Here is what the output of `$acl.Access | ft` looks like in all cases:

```
           FileSystemRights AccessControlType IdentityReference                IsInherited InheritanceFlags PropagationFlags
           ---------------- ----------------- -----------------                ----------- ---------------- ----------------
                FullControl             Allow BUILTIN\Administrators                  True             None             None
                FullControl             Allow NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                     True             None             None
        Modify, Synchronize             Allow NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users        True             None             None
ReadAndExecute, Synchronize             Allow BUILTIN\Users                           True             None             None
```

I just can't get rid of that `Modify` flag. I've also tried targeting the file directly (replacing references to `$folder` with `$file` in the above code), but the result is the same. I've also tried replacing `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users` with just `Authenticated Users`, to no effect.

### Question:

Presumably I'm just doing it wrong. I'm fluent in Powershell, but have no previous experience using it to configure NTFS permissions. Perhaps I need to target the desired rule differently, or perhaps I need to overwrite it with `.SetAccessRule()` instead somehow...

How can I achieve this with Powershell? Thanks for your time.

Update: also perhaps inheritance is an issue? I'm unsure how to deal with that.

### Sources:

- Here is the example I've been working from (under the "Removing File or Folder Permissions) section: https://petri.com/how-to-use-powershell-to-manage-folder-permissions
- No examples of this use case are given on the official Set-Acl documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl
- I've also taken a look through the documentation for the  System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity class and its methods, however the method documentation gives no relevant examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemsecurity?view=net-5.0#methods

### My environment:

- Windows 10 x64 20H2
- Powershell 5.1
- In my testing, I'm running the code in an elevated Powershell console, as a user with local admin permissions. In practice the code will be run by MECM in the same script that copies the files down (presumably as SYSTEM or some such).

Comment: Update: I've solved it. Inheritance was indeed the issue. I will post an answer with the full solution shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out my problem was that the folder was inheriting the modify permission from `C:\`. Apparently modifying permissions when inheritance is enabled simply does nothing and throws no errors (>:/). The solution was to disable inheritance on the folder first (copying the existing permissions), and then the rest of the code works as expected.

In my case, simply removing all permissions for `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users` entirely was sufficient (and easier than performing modifications on the existing permissions), since `BUILTIN\Users` still has read permissions.

```
# Get the existing ACL
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $item

# Disable inheritance (copying permissions), so the modifications will actually take
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true)

# Perform the modification
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $item

# Get the existing ACL again
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $item

# Target and remove all permission for "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users"
$rules = $acl.Access | Where { $_.IdentityReference -eq $identity }
foreach($rule in $rules) {
    $acl.RemoveAccessRule($rule)
}

# Perform the modification
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $item
```